# Why i can't install autopy?

Tags: python, macos, macos-sierra, autopy

I'm using MacBook and Operating System is MacOS Sierra.

I use this command to install autopy:

```
sudo pip install autopy
```

But i get this error:

```
Collecting autopy
Downloading autopy-0.51.tar.gz (74kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 256kB/s 
Installing collected packages: autopy
 Running setup.py install for autopy ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-jSobWR/autopy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lxk785-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/autopy
copying autopy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/autopy
running build_ext
building 'color' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DIS_MACOSX -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/autopy-color-module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/autopy-color-module.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DIS_MACOSX -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MMBitmap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/MMBitmap.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/autopy-color-module.o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/MMBitmap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/autopy/color.so
building 'screen' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DIS_MACOSX -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/autopy-screen-module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/autopy-screen-module.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DIS_MACOSX -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/screen.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/screen.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DIS_MACOSX -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/screengrab.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/src/screengrab.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
src/screengrab.c:48:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CGDisplayBitsPerPixel' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        bitsPerPixel = (uint8_t)CGDisplayBitsPerPixel(displayID);
                                ^
src/screengrab.c:174:15: warning: 'kCGLPFAFullScreen' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        attribs[0] = kCGLPFAFullScreen;
                     ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/CGLTypes.h:98:2: note: 'kCGLPFAFullScreen' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        kCGLPFAFullScreen OPENGL_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_6)     =  54,
        ^
src/screengrab.c:191:2: warning: 'CGLSetFullScreen' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        CGLSetFullScreen(glContext);
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/OpenGL.h:73:17: note: 'CGLSetFullScreen' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern CGLError CGLSetFullScreen(CGLContextObj ctx) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_6);
                ^
src/screengrab.c:194:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glReadBuffer' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
        ^
src/screengrab.c:194:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_FRONT'
        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
                     ^
src/screengrab.c:197:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glFinish' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glFinish();
        ^
src/screengrab.c:199:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glGetError' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) return NULL;
            ^
src/screengrab.c:199:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_NO_ERROR'
        if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) return NULL;
                            ^
src/screengrab.c:207:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glPopClientAttrib' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPopClientAttrib(); /* Clear attributes previously set. */
        ^
src/screengrab.c:223:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glPushClientAttrib' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);
        ^
src/screengrab.c:223:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT'
        glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);
                           ^
src/screengrab.c:225:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glPixelStorei' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, BYTE_ALIGN); /* Force alignment. */
        ^
src/screengrab.c:225:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, BYTE_ALIGN); /* Force alignment. */
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:226:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:227:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:228:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:235:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glReadPixels' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glReadPixels(x, y, width, height,
        ^
src/screengrab.c:236:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_BGRA'
                     MMRGB_IS_BGR ? GL_BGRA : GL_RGBA,
                                    ^
src/screengrab.c:240:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV'
                     GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, /* Native format */
                     ^
10 warnings and 9 errors generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-jSobWR/autopy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lxk785-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-jSobWR/autopy/
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: I think you have to install openGL in your system gcc compiler first. Or find a binary distribution for your OS.

Comment: Thanks, but Lukasz's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue that for some reason wasn't fixed.

Issue: https://github.com/msanders/autopy/issues/75

It contains following workaround (commands to type in console):

```
brew install libpng
CFLAGS="-Wno-return-type" pip install git+https://github.com/potpath/autopy.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it works quite easily but if it doesn't then it's a bit tricky and you need to take run commands on your terminal.
First, check if a binary wheel is available for your machine by running:

```
$ pip install -U autopy
```

If that fails, install [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) and then run:

```
$ rustup default nightly-2019-10-05
$ pip install -U setuptools-rust
$ pip install -U autopy
```

sometimes     `$ rustup default nightly-2019-10-05` doesn't work due to unavailability of all packages, run `rustup install nightly 2019-10-05 --force`. But you have make sure that the rustup installation is properly done as it requires the installation of `[BuildTools][2]` as well

Answer (score 0):

You must Use 3.8 to install autopy. If you are not sure, type in your terminal:

```
python --version
```

**None version of python except 3.8 can install autopy.**

See other versions of autopy https://pypi.org/project/autopy/ .

Thanks.